# Ajax sending data to django python

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-places-api

Recreating a page to use django forms (current screen does not use any django forms implementation when rendering a template), to take in data from google places autocomplete. Basically just taking the response from google, converting it to json and making an ajax call with the form data and google data.

The problem I'm getting is when I serialize the form to pass the data into an ajax call the field that's storing this json value is coming in as a json wrapped in an array instead. Looking at the current page I have this does not happen and the data retrieved from google's api comes in as correctly.

The javascript that handles fetching the data from google is both the same and when applying it to the google-details field in the html, the value is updated by doing a .val(JSON.stringify()) on the data that is retrieved from google.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="google-details" name="google-details">
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit" id="submit">submit
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myForm").on("submit", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    do_ajax_call();
   }
  }

  function do_ajax_call() {
    let foo = $("#myForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/destination/',
      type: 'post',
      data: foo,
      success: function(res) {
      //Do stuff
      }
    })

  }
</script>
```

data that I'm getting from the ajax on the updated page

```
['{"address_components":[{"long_name":"20","short_name":"20","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"West 34th Street","short_name":"W 34th St.","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Manhattan","short_name":"Manhattan","types":["sublocality_level_1","sublocality","political"]},{"long_name":"New York","short_name":"New York","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"New York County","short_name":"New York County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"New York","short_name":"NY","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"10001","short_name":"10001","types":["postal_code"]}],"business_status":"OPERATIONAL","formatted_address":"20 W 34th St., New York, NY 10001, USA","name":"Empire State Building","place_id":"ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE","types":["tourist_attraction","museum","point_of_interest","establishment"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=15074921902713971043","html_attributions":[]}', '', '', '']
```

expected, data that I'm getting from the current iteration.

```
{"address_components":[{"long_name":"20","short_name":"20","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"West 34th Street","short_name":"W 34th St.","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Manhattan","short_name":"Manhattan","types":["sublocality_level_1","sublocality","political"]},{"long_name":"New York","short_name":"New York","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"New York County","short_name":"New York County","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"New York","short_name":"NY","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"United States","short_name":"US","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"10001","short_name":"10001","types":["postal_code"]}],"business_status":"OPERATIONAL","formatted_address":"20 W 34th St., New York, NY 10001, USA","name":"Empire State Building","place_id":"ChIJaXQRs6lZwokRY6EFpJnhNNE","types":["tourist_attraction","museum","point_of_interest","establishment"],"url":"https://maps.google.com/?cid=15074921902713971043","html_attributions":[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little but unclear, why you need help. All works normally.

If you want to skip empty elements - you can filter it on js side:

```
let foo = $("#myForm").serialize().filter(bit => bit);
```

If you want to send only first not empty element in list:

```
let foo = $("#myForm").serialize().filter(bit => bit);
foo = foo.length ? foo[0] : {}
```

If you want to skip empty elements - you can filter it on python side:

```
data = (bit for bit in serialized_data if bit)
```

If you want to get only first not empty element in list:

```
data = (bit for bit in serialized_data if bit)
data = next(data, None)
```

But i feel, something wrong in logic in question. I can not define it.

Comment: Yeah I figured this would be pretty unclear. The work around I've done was more just to get the value using jquery and pass the parameter itself, instead of letting the serialize function on the form do its thing. 

On python's side I would have to do a `request.POST.getlist("google-details")` just to be able to read the value being passed through the ajax call. With the older iteration of my code doing this, never had this problem. Both of the code bases are identical besides one is using django forms, and the new one (my current problem) isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up as one of my comments said just pulling the data directly from the field and storing it in a variable and sending it to back to python through an ajax call